# How to Take Values from text Box and Pass to Process Builder

Tags: java, svn, processbuilder

Sorry or Asking Very Basic question and for my English

I am Trying to Run SVN Export Command in Cygwin which works fine. Now I want to Paas Parameters using Text Box How to achive this.

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("cmd"," /c svn export http://My_svn/trunk/data/ d:\\NirajData -r 118 --username niraj --password abc123 --force --non-interactive");
```

Here in above Code I want to Pass

```
SVN_path=http://My_svn/trunk/data/ 
Destination Path=d:\\NirajData
Svn Versio=118
svnusername=niraj
svnpassword=abc123
```

Please Help me for Doing this.
Thanks in Advance..

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it correctly, instead of invoking process builder directly you need to show GUI component:
- show GUI component containing boxes for your values and OK\Cancel buttons.
 
- when OK is pushed construct the command manually part by part based on values from GUI filled by user
 
- you can also add some checks if all of needed values are filled...
 
- invoke the command using process builder.